# Tables formatting

Tags: tables

How can I get this table to work? Thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{}l 
                S[table-format=-1.2(2)
                 *{2}S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
                S[table-format=4.0] } 
\toprule
\textbf{Res.}  & {\textbf{Expt.(a)}} & {\textbf{Expt.(b)}} & {\textbf{Theor.}} \\
\midrule
1 & -0.57   & -0.23  &          \\
4 & 1.90    & 1.97(10)   & 1.98     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption [}}\label{}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier  
\end{document}
```

Comment: It doesnt compile. gives me error

Comment: ! LaTeX error: "kernel/misplaced-equals-sign"!! Misplaced equals sign in key-value input 439!! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... \textbf{Res.} & {

Comment: ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.<recently read> \endtemplate ...textbf{Expt.(a)}} & {\textbf{Expt.(b)}} &

Comment: I do not know what you mean, sorry

Comment: ! LaTeX error: "kernel/misplaced-equals-sign"!! Misplaced equals sign in key-value input 15!! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... \textbf{Res.} & {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example file contains various syntax errors. Example after fixing:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{
    >{}l
    S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
    *{2}{S[table-format=-1.2(2)]}
    % S[table-format=4.0] % unused
  }
    \toprule
    \textbf{Res.}
    & {\textbf{Expt.\,(a)}}
    & {\textbf{Expt.\,(b)}}
    & {\textbf{Theor.}} \\
    \midrule
    1 & -0.57   & -0.23  &          \\
    4 & 1.90    & 1.97(10)   & 1.98     \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table with numbers}\label{tab:numbers}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The column types are not changed, because the real table is probably larger and the values of the other rows are not known.

Comment: there is one small problem. it is that the (10) value is error so it should be in the format of +-10.